# how to package only default language with android gradle resConfigs

Tags: android, build.gradle

I know how to restrict language support using resConfigs :

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    resConfig "en"
}
```

But how to restrict language to support only the default one (in values/ folder) ? Is there a way to avoid packaging any language resources stored in values-xx/ folders ?

Thanks

Comment: have you found an answer?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The configuration probably should rather be (tested with Gradle 6.1.1):

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res {
                exclude "**/values-de/*.xml"
                exclude "**/values-he/*.xml"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One needs one line per language tag, because of all the other directories matching `values-*`.

And to check which resources are actually being packaged:

```
sourceSets.main.res.getExcludes().each { println "Found exclude: $it" }
sourceSets.main.res.sourceFiles.each { println "File in source set: " + it }
```

For regular Java projects, this would be directory `resources` instead of the Android-specific `res`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by  specifying the exclude on the filter field:

```
android {
    sourceSets.main.res.filter.exclude '**/values/whatever.xml'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
sourceSets.getByName("main") {
    res.exclude("**/values-**/*.xml")
}
```

Comment: This assumes that `en` would be the "default" for everybody (it is only the default for Android).

Comment: @MartinZeitler That's a good point. Given "en" is the default this worked for me.